# Mysql SUM by Column with LIMIT

Tags: mysql, group-by, sum, limit

I have this table that amount directly from Excel in CSV format. 
I have ordered for the Year, and Pilot Points in descending order,
then the sum of the first six results for each rider
(if the rows are less than or equal to six I have to add only the rows)
and then extract from the resulting table only the first three best results in order to establish a ranking.

Thanks in advance

```
INSERT INTO `migliorio` (`Anno`, `Pilota`, `km`, `punti`, `media`) 
VALUES (2013, 'Pilota 2', 6.33, 6.33, 21.86),
       (2013, 'Pilota 2', 4.75, 4.75, 15.15),
       (2013, 'Pilota 2', 4.07, 4.07, 11.84),
       (2013, 'Pilota 1', 9.73, 9.73, 19.61),
       (2013, 'Pilota 1', 6.97, 9.76, 9.56),
       (2013, 'Pilota 1', 7.59, 7.59, 26.27),
       (2013, 'Pilota 1', 8.18, 8.18, 24.56),
       (2013, 'Pilota 1', 7.24, 7.24, 12.27),
       (2013, 'Pilota 1', 11.77, 11.77, 17.20),
       (2013, 'Pilota 2', 5.98, 5.98, 18.68),
       (2013, 'Pilota 2', 6.09, 7.31, 15.60),
       (2013, 'Pilota 2', 10.99, 13.19, 13.20),
       (2013, 'Pilota 3', 20.29, 24.35, 18.72),
       (2013, 'Pilota 3', 29.30, 35.16, 18.39),
       (2013, 'Pilota 1', 10.34, 10.34, 13.88),
       (2013, 'Pilota 1', 7.65, 10.71, 14.55),
       (2013, 'Pilota 1', 8.21, 8.21, 27.53),
       (2013, 'Pilota 1', 13.57, 16.28, 11.94);
```

Comment: Do you need the sum for each column or only for one?

Do you want the three best driver at the end?

Comment: Should I make the sum of the six best results column "points" for each pilot oppre the first six rows for each rider if I order the table by Year, Pilot and points. 
And this is a query. 
The secoda query should extract the pilots three miles from the table previously generated.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DISTINCT T0.Pilota,
(SELECT SUM(km) FROM migliorio WHERE Pilota = T0.Pilota LIMIT 6) As SUM_km,
(SELECT SUM(punti) FROM migliorio WHERE Pilota = T0.Pilota LIMIT 6) As SUM_punti,
(SELECT SUM(media) FROM migliorio WHERE Pilota = T0.Pilota LIMIT 6) As SUM_media
 FROM `migliorio` AS T0
ORDER BY (SELECT SUM(media) FROM migliorio WHERE Pilota = T0.Pilota) DESC
LIMIT 3
```

An hint for your table construct. In this query, I link the name field (Pilota). Use int ID field with a ID of the Pilot. Because:

1. The queries are faster
2. Use primary keys to prevent dupicated keys
3. No misspelling in the values (e.g "Pilota 1" and "Pilota1" are not the same)

Comment: I completely agree with you, but I get the file from a spreadsheet that I do not create. 
I know for a fact that where I wrote Pilot 1, Pilot 2 .... is the name of the pilot.

Answer (score 0):

Using variables, something like this:-

```
SELECT `Pilota`, SUM(`km`), SUM(`punti`), SUM(`media`)
FROM 
(
    SELECT `Anno`, `Pilota`, `km`, `punti`, `media`, @seq:=if(@prev_pilota = Pilota, @seq + 1, 1) AS aSeq, @prev_pilota := Pilota
    FROM migliorio
    CROSS JOIN (SELECT @seq := 0, @prev_pilota := '') Sub1
    ORDER BY `Anno`, `Pilota`, `km`, `punti`, `media`
) Sub0
WHERE aSeq <= 6
GROUP BY Pilota
```

SQL fiddle here:-

http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7310f/4

However not sure how you want to chose which km / punti / media are the 6 that you want for each Pilota (or do you want it per Pilota and Anno?)

EDIT - Modified to just sum up the points from the top 6 points for each pilota / anni:-

```
SELECT `Pilota`, Anno, SUM(`punti`)
FROM 
(
    SELECT `Anno`, `Pilota`, `km`, `punti`, `media`, @seq:=if(@prev_pilota = Pilota and @prev_anno = anno, @seq + 1, 1) AS aSeq, @prev_pilota := Pilota, @prev_anno := anno
    FROM migliorio
    CROSS JOIN (SELECT @seq := 0, @prev_pilota := '', @prev_anno :=0) Sub1
    ORDER BY `Anno`, `Pilota`, `punti` DESC
) Sub0
WHERE aSeq <= 6
GROUP BY Pilota, Anno
```

EDIT - A short explanation

This uses a sub query, setting a couple of SQL variables. These initialise a sequence number (@seq), the previous pilota (@prev_pilota) and the previous anno (@prev_anno).

The main sub query then gets all the records from the table migliorio, ordered by anno, pilota and punti (descending for punti). This way all the records for a pilota / anno will be together. It adds 1 to @seq if the pilota and anno are the same as the stored pilota and anno (stored in @prev_pilota and @prev_anno), and if not sets @seq to 1, and saves @seq for that row to the column name aSeq. This way each row for a pilota / anno has a sequence numbe. The sequence number will be 1 for the highest punti for a pilota / anno, going up as the punti goes down.

The outer query takes the results of this sub query and sums up the values of Punti for a pilota / anno (this is specified by the GROUP BY), but the WHERE clause checks that aSeq is <= 6, so any row for a pilota / anno other than those with a sequence number between 1 and 6 is ignored.

Hope that helps

Comment: YEEAHH! It works perfectly! Thank you very much Kickstart.
A favor, would you explain me step by step what makes the Select? 
I would like to understand better to learn.